# Set an integer using ListIterator

Tags: java, random, arraylist, iterator, listiterator

The task I want to accomplish is to set a random int from 0 to 1000, for each element of an `ArrayList` of 1,000,000 elements. I did it successfully using simple `for loops`, but now I want to obtain this trough the `ListIterator` and its `set()` method.

```
static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List rInt = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            rInt.add(i);
        }

        List hMSAL = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            hMSAL.add(i);

        }
        ListIterator<Integer> gI = hMSAL.listIterator();
        while (gI.hasNext()) {
            Collections.shuffle(rInt);
            int rand = (int) rInt.get(333);
            gI.next();
            gI.set(rand);
            int f = gI.next();
            System.out.println(++i + " " + f);
        }
```

***The problem is the output.***

```
Output:
```

1 2

2 4

3 6

4 8

5 10
...

**Q:** What should I modify in my code, so for each **i** from 1 to 1,000,000 the assigned value would be a random integer from 1 to 1000.

Comment: You're calling next() twice in the loop. You shouldn't. Also, your random genaration is awfully slow. Why do you shuffle a list at each iteration. What's wrong with random.nextInt(1000)?

Comment: Unrelated code review: Don't use raw types. Use `List<Integer>` and `ArrayList<>`. Also, you can write `1000000` as `1_000_000` for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now if I got you right, but try this:

Change

```
// ...
gI.next();
gI.set(rand);
int f = gI.next();
// ...
```

To

```
// ...
Integer f = gI.next();
gI.set(rand);
// ...
```

If this doesn't result in the desired output, please clarify your question.